# Python Error -- "self" is not defined

Tags: python, self

I recently started learning Python and I ran into an error with classes and "self" not being defined. I know that there are a lot of questions about this issue, but I could not figure out the problem with my code based on those answers.

```
import random

class Encrypt():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Encryption using RSA Algorithms")

    x = input("Do you want to Encrypt or Decrypt?")
    if x=="Encrypt":
        print("Redirecting...")
    else:
        print("Redirecting...")

    choice_1 = "Encrypt"
    choice_2 = "Decrypt"

    if x==choice_1:
        y  = input("Do you have a public key?")
        if y=="Yes":
            print("Redirecting...")
        else:
            print("Generating a key...")
            print(self.publickey_generate()) #Error here that self is not defined

    else:
        z = input("What is your private key?")

    def publickey_generate(self):
        for output in range (0,1000):
            public = random.randint(0, 1000)
            if public <= 500:
                public += public
            else:
                public = public - 1
```

This is the code that I am making, it is an encryption and decryption software. The error (marked by a comment) is,

```
line 23, in Encrypt
print(self.publickey_generate(). NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I don't know why this is happening. Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: change `class Encrypt()` to `class Encrypt(object):` ?

Comment: Your indentation needs to be corrected

Comment: It looks like the code is not indented properly under the ``__init__`` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indents should look like:

```
import random

class Encrypt():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Encryption using RSA Algorithms")

        x = input("Do you want to Encrypt or Decrypt?")
        if x=="Encrypt":
            print("Redirecting...")
        else:
            print("Redirecting...")

        choice_1 = "Encrypt"
        choice_2 = "Decrypt"

        if x==choice_1:
            y  = input("Do you have a public key?")
        if y=="Yes":
            print("Redirecting...")
        else:
            print("Generating a key...")
            print(self.publickey_generate()) #Error here that self is not defined

        else:
            z = input("What is your private key?")

    def publickey_generate(self):
        for output in range (0,1000):
            public = random.randint(0, 1000)
            if public <= 500:
                public += public
            else:
                    public = public - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

self is refering to the instance of the object when you are in a method of the class.

Here, in line 23, you are using it directly in your class (which is not a good way to do it in my opinion). It should work if you remove the self before `publickey_generate()`

But honestly it seems a really odd way for object programming... You should put all your code in the class methods and only global variable outside (if needed). So in your case, the easiest would be to put all your code (except `publickey_generate()`) in your init method